# Как ограничить вывод текста до определенного стоп слова?

Tags: php, html

Всем привет. Есть блок с описанием блюда. Хочу ограничить вывод текста до стоп слов (Порция и/или Калорийность), если встречаются в тексте с помощью `$rest = substr()`, но ведь эта фунция ориентируется на порядковые номера в параметрах, а не стоп слова, да?

```html
<td>
  <p><strong>Состав и вес блюда</strong>
    <br>Состав: <em>лапша яичная, курица, чеснок, лук, соевый соус, индийский орех</em>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <strong>Порция</strong>: <em>150г.</em>
  </p>
  <hr>
  <strong>Калорийность</strong>
  <br>
  <em>Белки(100г): 11,49г.</em>
  <br>
  <em>Жиры(100г): 22,32г.</em>
  <br>
  <em>Углеводы(100г): 32,33г.</em>
  <br>
  <em>Энерг. ценность(100г): 368,39калл.</em>
  <p></p>
</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите функцию [stristr()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.stristr.php) и ее парамент before_needle

Возможно, это то, что вам надо.

Comment: записал хитро вот так `$subdescription = stristr($subdescription, 'Калорийность', true); $subdescription = stristr($subdescription, 'Порция', true); var_dump($subdescription);`
но, к сожалению, остается косяк с тегами, в которые слова оборачиваются

Answer (score 1):

Я бы тебе советовал использовать функцию explode().

```
var $stopSlova = ["Порция","Калорийность"];

function stopText($text="", $stopSlova=[]){
      foreach($stopSlova as $slovo){
         $text = explode($slovo, $stopSlova);
         $text = $text[0];
         if(isset($text[1])){$text[0].=$slovo;}//Если нужно разбивать по слову включительно (само слово оставалось в конце): Если строка разбилась - на 2 или более части (т.е. слово присутствовало) - в конец прибавляется это слово 
      }
      return $text;
}

$new_text = stopText($old_text, $stopSlova);
```

Другая вот задача - с корректной обработкой закрывающихся тегов при этом. Это пока не соображу - видимо какой-то дополнительный обработчик вешать надо..=(

p.s.: еще можно - поиск-замена строки по регулярному вырожению попробовать, но в них я не очень силен, чтобы подсказать что-то конкретное...

UPD: Товарищ toxxxa навел на некоторую мысль по поводу тегов

```
var $stopSlova = array("Порция"=>"</strong></p>","Калорийность"=>"</strong>"); 
var $closeTagsAll="</td>";//Для сокращения записей, теги, кот. приходится закрывать для всех слов без исключения вынесем в отдельную переменую

function stopText($text="", $stopSlova=[]){
      foreach($stopSlova as  $slovo => $closeTags){
         $text = explode($slovo, $stopSlova);
         $text = $text[0];
         if(isset($text[1])){$text[0].=$slovo.$closeTags.$closeTagsAll;}//Добавляем вырезанное слово и закрываем все теги 
      }
      return $text;
}
```

Хотя, это давольно грубый способ: для каждого из стоп-слов прописывать закрывающие теги. toxxxa предлагал данный способ автомаезировать, но как это рализовать в даннном примере - это, видимо, он лучше представляет

Comment: стоп-стоп, так мне не сами слова нужно вырезать, а все содержимое после, если эти слова встречаются

Comment: @Вася, а данный код не вырезает слова. Здесь строка разбивается в цикле на две части по массиву слов. Затем возвращается все, что было до них.

Comment: Чтобы слово осталось - это можно вот так $text = $text[0].$slovo; - тогда все, что до слова + слово. Тут главный вопрос в данном случае с закрывающими тегами решить - чтобы верстка не поехала.

Comment: внес соответствующую правку

Comment: @Grinya Lesnoy спасибо, но к сожалению, ваш вариант не учитывает вариант, когда пользователь пожет не выделить текст жирным или не писать с нового абзаца

Comment: Твоя главная проблема в том, что ты не пытаешься сегментировать задачу (и поэтому ты не получаешь удолитворительного ответа). Т.е. реально у тебя не одна задача, а 2: 1) которую ты и описал - как разбить (ограничить) текст по стоп слову и 2) поиск незакрытых тегов на php. На 1й пункт ты получил несколько вариантов ответов. На 2й пункт, 1й же запрос в Гугле выдает несколько решений, в т.ч. на уже [готовую ф-цию](http://artkiev.com/blog/php-tags-close.htm)

Answer (score 1):

одной коммандой тут не обойдешься. как я понимаю, определённой структуры документа нет, и эти стоп-слова могут встретиться в любом месте документа? тогда придется перебирать все строчки в цикле, искать открывающие `html`-теги и закрывать их вручную.

предлагаю следующий алгоритм:

1. определим массив, в который запишем все теги, которые нужно закрыть (в данном примере `array('td','p','strong','em')`
2. начинаем просматривать текст до тех пор, пока не будет найдено стоп-слово. если попадается открывающий тег, запомним в стек, если закрывающий - удалим из стека.
3. как только найдено стоп-слово, удалим из стека последний тег (`strong` в данном случае), раз мы удаляем слово, то и закрывать тег не нужно.
4. по очереди выаскиваем из стека все открытые теги и закрываем их.

Comment: Если в вопросе речь идет не о грубом обрезе какой-то строки, то алгоритм по идее верный. Если я правильно понял идею, то здесь не учтены теги, которые закрывать не требуется. Это одно из исключений, с которым придется столкнуться, и реализовать это будет немного сложнее, чем здесь написано.

Comment: @mJeevas почему не учтены? а, да, я упомянул о массиве с тегами, которые нужно закрывать только в п.1 и дальше о нем не вспоминал. разумеется, в п.2 нужно проверять, если тег есть в массиве из п.1, только тогда бросать его в стек.

Answer (score 0):

Можно поставить всем братьям и сестрам после стоп тега атрибут `style="display:none"`